# Show/Hide Window by Clicking button in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I want to show/hide a window in swift by clicking a button from main window. Beginsheet is showing the window, but endsheet is not closing the window. My appdelegate code is given:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    var settingsController: SettingsController?

    @IBAction func inSettings(sender: NSObject?)
    {
        settingsController = SettingsController(windowNibName: "SettingsController")
        window.beginSheet(settingsController!.window!, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func outSettings(sender: NSObject?)
    {
        window.endSheet(settingsController!.window!)
    }

}
```

SettingsController:

```
import Cocoa

class SettingsController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 Solution:

Lets say that you have WindowA and WindowB. You want to open WindowB but first You want to hide WindowA.
Connect windows with a segue. (Select "Show" as segues "Kind" property) And you need a static class to keep hidden window. in WindowA override shouldPerformSegue and keep WindowA as a static NSWindow object.

```
 override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

        YourStaticClass.WindowA = self.view.window
        self.view.window?.orderOut(self)

        return true
    }
```

orderOut(self) hides the window. Then WindowB will be opened.

In WindowB's view controller use a function to close windowB and show hidden WindowA:

```
 @IBAction func btnBack_Click(_ sender: NSButton) {  

    YourStaticClass.WindowA?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(YourStaticClass.WindowA)    
    self.view.window?.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `endSheet` to end a document-modal sheet session. Like this:

```
@IBAction func outSettings(sender: NSObject?)
{
    settingsController!.window!.endSheet(settingsController!.window!)
}
```

**EDIT**: You need to actually close the window in your completion handler you call `orderOut`, like this:

```
@IBAction func inSettings(sender: NSObject?)
{
    settingsController = SettingsController(windowNibName: "SettingsController")
    window.beginSheet(settingsController!.window!) {
        settingsController!.window!.orderOut(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Devan "is not working" is not helpful. Is there an error, if yes which one? Does it just do nothing? Please give details.

Comment: @Aderstedt : I copied your code to the project and it says: AppDelegate.swift:30:16: Cannot invoke 'beginSheet' with an argument list of type '(NSWindow, () -> _)'

Comment: @EricD. : There is no error, But it does nothing. endsheet is supposed to close the window, but it doesn't. Is there any other way other than beginsheet to open a window from another window?

Comment: Yes, there's plenty, look at [NSWindow class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/endSheet:) it contains everything.